# Extend Ceva's theorem to angles?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Ceva's theorem, as described in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem)

> Given a triangle ABC, let the lines AO, BO and CO be drawn from the
> vertices to a common point O (not on one of the sides of ABC), to meet
> opposite sides at D, E and F respectively. (The segments AD, BE, and
> CF are known as cevians.) Then, using signed lengths of segments,
> [image: Ceva]
> $$\frac {AF}{FB}\cdot \frac  {BD}{DC}\cdot \frac  {CE}{EA}=1.$$

, is about the lengths of the triangle's sides split by a commont point.

I wonder, if it can be extended to angles? -- if we name angle OAB as $\alpha_1$, OAC as $\alpha_2$, OBC as $\beta_1$, OBA as $\beta_2$, OCA as $\gamma_1$ and OCB as $\gamma_2$, is there a conclusion of the relationship among them?

Comment: See ["Trigonometric Form of Ceva's Theorem"](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml) at Cut-the-Knot. This result is well-known, so it's surprising that the Wikipedia article doesn't include it. (BTW: Good instincts! :)

Comment: Additionally, if you search for that topic on MathSE, you may say many posts using this theorem.